# 配列の標準偏差を一度にもとめたい

Tags: python, numpy, array

pythonでnumpyをつかって標準偏差を配列に計算させているのですが、forを使うのでとても遅くて困っています。
配列の標準偏差を一度に求める方法があればうれしいのですが、良い方法をお持ちの方がおられましたら、ご助言ください。

Answer (score 3):

[`numpy.std`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html)という、そのまま標準偏差を求めてくれる関数があります。

ちなみに不偏標準偏差を求めるときは`ddof=1`にする必要があるようです。

---

**追記(2017/10/04 22:19)**

`axis`(軸)を指定すれば、その軸に沿って標準偏差を計算してくれます。なので、配列の配列に対して、各配列の標準偏差を計算したいときは、`axis=1`と指定すればよいです。

```
>>> a = np.array([[31,19,1],[2,1,1]])
>>> np.std(a, axis=1)
array([ 12.32882801,   0.47140452])
```

Comment: ご助言ありがとうございます。一度に複数の配列の標準偏差を取得したいのですが・・・